# rails 2 to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

how to upgrade a rails 2 plugin to rails 3?

Comment: What specific problems are you having? Most of my validation plugins "just worked." I only had to change the load call in init.rb.

Answer (score 2):

This handbook will tell you exactly what to do:

http://www.railsupgradehandbook.com/

Upgrading a legacy rails 2 -3 is a tedious task ... many errors will arouse especially if the application is big and old. I would also suggest you watch railscast episodes 225,226 and 226.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this tutorial:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2
- There are a part 3 too

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available for upgrading rails version.
Try this:

https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's not that hard to upgrade Rails 2 app to Rails 2. Here is a sample guide:

http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3

The guidelines that applies to apps should apply to plugins as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade a 2.x app to 3,
there is an episode in [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/)  [Upgrading to Rails 3 Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=225) which explains about rails_upgrade plugin that help to determine what needs upgrading.

To upgrade plugins to Rails 3.0
http://boldr.net/upgrade-plugins-gems-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't upgrade the rails 2 plugin to rails 3 plugin. You can always change the structure of the code suitable to rails 3 coding but that doesn't mean upgrade. You might need to check out the repository if you could find the version suitable to rails 3 for that plugin

Comment: if you are looking for rails 2 application to rails 3 application then there are many ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can find a peepcode for that : https://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf

Or the railscasts is very nice too